# Spring JPA save() inserting instead of updating

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-data-jpa

I have a table in below format

```
Customer:
ID PK
value1
value2
address
```

I have unique constraint for value1 and value2.

While saving/updating I will not be having value for ID

So here is my service class code to update customer:

```
@Transactional
  public void saveCustomer(String value1,String value2, String address) {

    Customer customer = customerRepository.findByValue1AndValue2(value1,value2).orElse(new Customer());

    customer.setValue1(value1);
    customer.setValue2(value2);
    customer.setAddress(address);
    customerRepository.save(customer);

  }
```

I am getting "Cannot insert duplicate key row in object  error."

When I get the  customer object using findByValue1AndValue2, it will have id orrect? so it should do update not insert

Adding my customer class:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "customer")
@Data
@NoArgsConstructor
@AllArgsConstructor
@EntityListeners(AuditingEntityListener.class)
public class Customer{

@Id
  @GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.IDENTITY)
  @Column(name = "id")
  private Integer id;

@Column(name="value1")
private String value1;

@Column(name="value2")
private String value2;

@Column(name="address")
private String address;

 @CreatedDate
  @Column(name="created_date", nullable = false, updatable = false)
  private Date created_date;

  @LastModifiedDate
  @Column(name="updated_date")
  private Date updated_date;
}
```

I have added annotation @EnableTransactionManagement
Is there any thing specific need to be done

Please help me with this issue.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Debug your code and see if a new customer is being returned.

Comment: @pringi i am running this in multi thread environment. When I got the exception Id was 0 for this object. I even tried adding synchronized in the method.

Answer (score 0):

The catch lies in `orElse(new Customer())`. The `orElse()` method always invokes the provided function, even when the Optional is non-empty. In this scenario, a new object is created each time, and since the method is transactive, the object will persist. Alternatively, you can use `orElseGet()`, which executes the Supplier method only when the Optional value is not present.